# REGEX: url with any query param OR url with any query param and an especific hash

Tags: regex

I need to make a regex to cover the following:

domain/path/**?anything** --> YES

domain/path/**?anything**#/*specificHash* --> YES

domain/path/**?anything**#/otherHash --> NO

**My try**: I have made this regex excluding otherHashs:

domain/path/?(?!.*(otherHash1|otherHash2|otherHash3))

It works, but there are a lot of them... I want to make it easier just including my *specificHash*

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [`domain/path/\?[^/]*(?:/specificHash)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/oSOblT/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew according to [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-24), "The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
   within the query component", so checking for a slash wouldn't be enough, you'd have to check for the `#`

Comment: @Aaron: *Feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes*. The question does not sound clear enough to me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew of course this isn't specific to regex, and the question does that mistake too. I decided to notify you since your regex seems perfect to me apart from this point, but the information is more relevant to the asker. I'll post an answer of mine that should handle query strings containing `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to match urls that have a query string followed by a specific hash OR a query string without any hash ; here's how I would match that :

```
domain/path/?[^#]*(?:#/specificHash)?$
```

The `[^#]*` regex fragment should match any query string but no hash fragment. It can only be followed by an optional `#/specificHash` and the end of the string.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vD8MH0/2) (forked from @Wiktor Stribiżew's test cases).